# Find m using random variables

Tags: statistics

Let X be a continous random variable:

$f(x)$ = {$ mx^4$ for $0 \le x \le 1$, $0$ otherwise}

What is m, and what is $P(X < 0.7)$?

Comment: If $f$ is the probability density function of $X$, then it must have integral equal to 1 over $\mathbb{R}$. From there you can find $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$f$ must have integral equal to 1 over ℝ. 
$$\int_{0}^{1}mx^4dx=1$$